# Can't set cookie value

Tags: javascript, cookies, setcookie

Cookie values are not displayed for fname, production, prod From. Everytime returns "null null null". But the date of the last entry is displayed normally. 
It was necessary to create and process cookie, storing the value of any of the form fields (fname, production, prodForm), which was introduced at the last attempt of filling and the date.

Is the problem in function setCookie? (Because I get the date of the last visit) Please help to fix it.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Medicines</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="formaFunctions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cookies.js"></script>
</head>
    <body onload="checkCookie()">

        <h2>Medicines</h2>
        <div id="error"></div>
        <br>
        <form name="myForm" 
            action="http://10.12.53.159:8111/stud" 
            onsubmit="return validateForm()"
            method="post">

            <table border="2">
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Production:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="production"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Production form:</td>
                <td><select name="prodForm">
                    <option>Powder</option>
                    <option>Tablets</option>
                    <option>Dragee</option>
                    <option>Mixture</option>
                    <option>Salve</option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            </table>

            <p><input type="submit" value="Find" /></p>
        </form>
         <div id="cookie"></div>
    </body>
</html>
    </code>
```

Javascript:

```
function setCookie(name,value,exdays){
    var cookie_string = name+"="+escape(value);
    if(exdays){
        var exdate = new Date();
        exdate.setTime(exdate.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+exdate.toGMTString();
    }
    document.cookie = cookie_string;  
}

function getCookie(c_name){
    var i,x,y, ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(';');
    for(i=0; i<ARRcookies.length; i++){
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
        if (x==c_name){
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}

function checkCookie(){
    var string;
    var fname = getCookie("fname");
    var production = getCookie("production");
    var prodForm = getCookie("prodForm");
    if(fname!=null&&fname!=""){
        string = fname;
    }
    else{
        setCookie("fname", fname, 30);
    }


    if(production!=null&&production!=""){
        string += production;
    }
    else{
        setCookie("production", production, 30);
    }


    if(prodForm!=null&&prodForm!=""){
        string += prodForm;
    }
    else{
        setCookie("prodForm", prodForm, 30);
    }

    string += getCookie("lastVisit");
    document.getElementById('cookie').innerHTML = string;

    setCookie("lastVisit",new Date().toLocaleString(),30);
}
```

Comment: You do not have default values for the first two cookies in case those are not set.

Comment: Also, you discard the 'expires' string without appending that to the cookie, so expiration won't work either.